# How to not create a new MongoDB collection with winston?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, logging, winston

I am new to node.js and I am trying to use the node package winston-mongodb to log my messages to the database: `winston.add(new winston.transports.MongoDB({db: 'mongodb://localhost/myProject'}))`But if I start the application again, I run into this problem in the terminal: `winston-mongodb, initialization error:  MongoError: Collection already exists.`

The person whose tutorial I am following didn't seem to have this problem. Is it possible to tell winston that, if the collection already exists, simply write to it instead of creating a new one?

Comment: Link to documentation you are following and include your MongoDB server version.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-mongodb/pull/176).

To work around, you can create to MongoDB URI yourself and drop the collection (ignoring errors if it doesn't exist) prior to using winston.